# How do I generate parameters dependent on previous parameters

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verilator

I recently switched from VHDL to SystemVerilog, and I am converting some of my codes. I want to generate an array of local parameters based on 3 parameters: `SZ`, `L`, `MAX`.

[image: formula]

```
module test #(
    parameter int SZ = 1024,
    parameter int L = 35,
    parameter int MAX = 4
)()
//...
localparam int n[MAX:0] = ;//...

for(genvar i = 0; i < max; i++) begin: gg
//n[i] and n[i+1] will be used here
//There is a second generate loop here that uses n[i+1] and therefore n[i+1] has to be parameter.

end
```

I tried using a function to generate localparams, but I get an error that element assignment in function is not constant. I never had this issue in VHDL.

The only other option I can think of is to create the params inside the `for` `generate`, but how would I reference the initial value? Is there any other solution?

The simulator I am using is Verilator, but I also want the design to work in Xilinx Vivado.

I do not want to generate the parameters from an external script because I lose the ability to use Vivado's ability to run multiple synthesis/implementation in the same project with different parameters. That was what I used to do in VHDL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to initialize a parameter, you just have to have the output of the entire array as the result of the function. To do that, you need a typedef

```
typedef int array_type[MAX:0];

function array_type f();
  f[0]=SZ;
  for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
      f[i+1]=f[i]-((2*i)+1)*L)/2;
endfunction
localparam array_type n = f();
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Verilator. It gives unpacked array not allowed.

Comment: That's too bad Verillator doesn't support this synthesizable feature of SystemVerilog.  You should be able to modify the function to take one index argument that returns the one value you need and use the function instead of the `localparam n`

Comment: Can you try to use packed array?

Comment: @EnzeChi I got it working. Packed int doesn't work. I had to use packed 32-bits and it can be cast to int with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using packed array of 32-bits. Verilator doesn't support unpacked int with constants. Packed int is also not supported so I had to change the type to pack of 32-bits.

```
typedef [MAX:0][31:0] array_type;

function array_type f();
  f[0]=SZ;
  for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
      f[i+1]=f[i]-((2*i)+1)*L)/2;
endfunction
localparam array_type n = f();
```